# 2 questions: What bike is this? Also is this front wheel too big?

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike

[image: Full Bike]

[image: Tire Fit]

I found this bike one morning near my house and figured I'd bring it home to work on it/restore it. But I have no idea what make/model/year it is and I come asking for help. I can make out the word "SINTESI" on the side but that's about it. I tried to take a picture of the brand marks that were still visible but mind you, none of these may be stock. Also I stuck a 700c wheel on it and I was wondering if it's too big?

Cheers

Comment: The crank reads "Sugiano GLP Special" and the stem end that holds the handlebar has "CB" inscribed on it.

Comment: The wheel size looks spot on to me. Some road style bikes have minimal clearance above the tyre and the top of the fork. As long as the brake pads sit correctly on the rim and the wheel spins OK, I think you'll be fine. I presume it's been abandoned when you say you found it near your house, and that nobody is looking for it? :)

Comment: The front wheel does look a bit big compared to the rear, but I think this is because the front tire is fatter, and the rear tire is flat.

Comment: I would guess it's a bike from the early 80s.  If so it's designed for 27" wheels and tires.  700C wheels and tires would be a hair on the small side.

Comment: Age-identifying features:  Lugged frame, cotterless crank, stem shifters.  The brakes are a distinctive style that could be easily identified by someone into that sort of stuff.  The rear derailer appears quite short -- almost certainly only a 5-speed rear (though of course this can be checked).

Comment: Wait - You FOUND this bike near your house? Did it have a previous owner?

Comment: @DanielRHicks Unicrown forks didn't exist on mass produced road bikes in the early 80s. Also 27" wheels aren't nearly the era indicator you seem to think they are. It was common for the US and UK markets but not in continental Europe. If you see a Gitane with 27" you're looking at a bike made for the US/UK market, not the French market. Cranks are poor indicators as they're easily changed. I have a 3 year old frame running TA Pro Vis cranks! ;)

Answer (score 3):

Really hard to tell from the pictures. One thing I am certain of is that almost none of it is stock. A few observations:

1. The main frame is lugged, has full length brake cable housing and horizontal dropouts and starred bottle braze-ons. All of those date it to sometime prior to the late 80s. Split brake cable housing on road bikes became the norm on production bikes in the late 80s. Horizontal dropouts also largely disappeared from mass production bikes due to the introduction of indexed shifting in the mid to late 80s.
2. The fork is a unicrown model. Unicrown forks on massed produced road bikes didn't really become the norm until the early 90s. This one has a threaded headset so it mostly likely predates the late 90s by which time threadless became the norm on mass production bikes in the interest of cost savings.
3. Sintesi is an Italian company who came on the scene in the early 90s and are still around though no longer in the US market (AFAIK). That said, "Sintesi" is also Italian for "synthesis" so it could simply be a model name rather than actual brand (for example, Irio Tommasini offers a model called the "Sintesi" but this isn't one of his)
4. The stem is likely from the 70s. CB was a common brand back then. The brake levers likely say Universal, Weinmann or CLB. The exposed brake cable date them to prior to the late 80s at which point "aero" levers had become the norm.

Comment: Amazing you could determine all that by two pictures, I took a few more but it would only let me post two. Thanks for all the help everyone :)

Comment: Way too many years working in shops, especially in the 80s! Also years spent working at centuries, races, etc. seeing all sorts of bikes.